# TypeError when using jscrollpane

Tags: jquery, jscrollpane, typeerror

Folks, this one is killing me....

I'm using jscrollpane in a lot of places on my site and all is fine. On one (ironically simple page), i have some edit fields that happen to be in a div that has jscrollpane applied to it.

Scrolling is fine. the page and everything is fine. The problem is that safari, chrome and firefox report the following error:

```
TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function (evaluating 'c.replace(/\=\s*([^'"\]]*)\s*\]/g,"='$1']")')   
in jquery-1.5.min.js:16
```

this error shows up when the focus is on the edit field (i actually stripped the form down to ONE field) and any key is pressed. So if i go to edit the field and i hit even the Alt/Option, Command, ctrl keys, that error is generated and its counter goes up. hitting ESC makes the error counter jumps by a lot.

if i remove jscrollpane and let the OS show its scrollbars, then the error disappears!!!

I have changed the name, size, id, class,.... of the edit box with no difference :(

I'm really puzzled by this one. Any thoughts, clues???

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

it looks like enableKeyboardNavigation is the culprit. Make it false in settings and all is well

Comment: buddy!!!!!! how the heck did figure this one out???? initial tests confirm it as a solution. I don't get why I only had the problem on one page and not on any of the other pages that use jscrollpane. Thank you so much for responding to this question :)